# beautifulsoup Replace tag contents text with dictionary value

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I made a dictionary;

```
mydic = {
'ProductName1': 'mp1',
'ProductName2 : 'mp2',
'ProductName3' : 'mp3',
'ProductName4' : 'mp4'
}

url = "https://www.example.com"
result = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")

tagnames = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "one-line font-size-md"})
```

The output is list like this:

```
[< d i v c l a s s ="o n e - l i n e   f o n t - s i z e - m d " > P r o d u c t N a m e 1 < / d i v > ,   < d i v   c l a s s = " o n e - l i n e  
 f o n t - s i z e -  m d " > P r o d u c t N a m e 2 < / d i v > ,   < d i v   c l a s s = " o n e -l i n e   f o n t - s i z e - m d " > P r o d u c t N a m e 3 < / d i v > ,   < d i v   c l a s s = " o n e - l i n e   f o n t - s i z e - m d " > P r o d u c t N a m e 4 < / d i v > ]
```

I want to replace ProductName1 with `mydic` values `mp1`, `mp2` , `mp3`, `mp4` and save html file with replaced. I tried to change the format to string and replace but it couldn't be true.

Answer (score 1):

soup.find_all() will give you list of elements matching the selector .

you can try something like this

```
mydict = { 
    "ProductName1" : "mp1",
    "ProductName2" : "mp2",
    "ProductName3" : "mp3",
    "ProductName4" : "mp4",
}

html = '''<div class ="one-line font-size-md">ProductName1</div> <div  class ="one-line font-size-md"> ProductName2 </div> <div  class ="one-line font-size-md"> ProductName3 </div> <div  class ="one-line font-size-md"> ProductName4 </div>'''

sp = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
divs = sp.find_all('div','one-line font-size-md')

for div in divs :
    div.string = mydict[div.text.lstrip().rstrip()]


with open("output.html", "wb") as file:
    file.write(sp.prettify("utf-8"))
```